# Pass websockets and timeout values in nginx ingress controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I want to configure the following settings in my `nginx` ingress controller deployment

```
proxy_socket_keepalive -> on 
proxy_read_timeout -> 3600
proxy_write_timeout ->3600
```

However I am unable to find them as `annotations` [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/), although they appear in the list of available `nginx` [directives](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_socket_keepalive).

Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `proxy_write_timeout`. I assume you meant the [proxy_send_timeout](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_send_timeout).

Both:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout
```

and:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout
```

Can be found [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-timeouts) and [here](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/#general-customization).

As for the `proxy_socket_keepalive`, unfortunately, this option cannot be set via annotations. You may want to nest it in the Nginx config, for example:

```
location / {
     client_max_body_size 128M;
     proxy_buffer_size 256k;
     proxy_buffers 4 512k;
     proxy_busy_buffers_size 512k;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_socket_keepalive on;
```